# What is the correct encoding for Indy Tidhttp for posting XML Files?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, idhttp, delphi-xe4, txmldocument

I notice I have invalid characters for XML files in an application who use Indy Client (I actually use default parameters for IdHttp)

Here is my code :

```
  ts := TStringList.Create;
  try
    ts.Add('XML=' + AXMLDoc.XML.Text));
    HTTPString := IdHTTPClient.Post('http://' + FHost + ':' + IntToStr(FPort) + FHttpRoot, ts);
  finally
    ts.Free;
  end;
```

My XML file is UTF-8 encoded.

What I have to do get good encoding on my server (I also use Indy for server) ?

Comment: Use what is in the `encoding` attribute value in your XML header. If it's UTF-8 then I would try [`this code`](http://pastebin.com/tQU43EiP).

Comment: it's encoded with UTF-8 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UTF-8 is the default charset that `TIdHTTP` uses for submitting a `TStringList` object. The real issue is that XML should not be submitted using a `TStringList` to begin with, even with a proper charset. The reason is because the `TIdHTTP.Post(TStrings)` method implements the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type, and thus url-encodes the `TStringList` content, which can break XML if the receiver is not expecting that.  So unless the receiver is actually expecting a real `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoded request, XML should be transmitted using the `TIdHTTP.Post(TStream)` method instead so the raw XML bytes are preserved as-is.

Comment: It now works well on Windows :)
It compile for iOS but when I try to execute on iOS, it make HTTP 500 Internal Server Error : what can be the error ?

Comment: There is no way to know without comparing the actual HTTP request data from both platforms. How are you creating and submitting the XML exactly?

Comment: XML is an TXMLDocument and I make like this http://pastebin.com/PXq4vC1Z 
It's a component and it is used for Win32 and iOS

Comment: `TStringStream` uses `SysUtils.TEncoding`, so it also can corrupt the XML if you don't use the correct encoding. XML defaults to UTF-8 so try specifying `TEncoding.UTF8` in the `TStringStream` constructor.

Comment: Again, you need to get a capture of the raw HTTP request data being transmitted by both platforms and compare them for any differences. Either a required parameter is missing, or the XML is encoded differently, or the like. A 500 reply generally means the server encountered a critical error, usually due to bad input.